# Doxygen COMPACT_LATEX seems to generate incorrect Latex

Tags: latex, doxygen, pdflatex

I am trying to generate Latex output from Doxygen (1.8.9.1) on Windows 7 with DoxyWizard. My code is a small Python class and I just want the few pages that describe the class and its members or methods. Doxygen and Latex work fine but generate lots of empty or nearly empty pages (save a tree!).

When I set `COMPACT_LATEX=YES` then the first line of refman.tex becomes `\documentclass[twoside]{article}` . When I run the Make.bat (which in turn runs the Makefile), the Latex processing halts with:

> `! Undefined control sequence.`
>   `l.132 \backmatter`

This is telling me that the article class is not expecting the usual front/back matter that would go in a book. With `COMPACT_LATEX=NO`, the first line is `\documentclass[twoside]{book}` and of course it runs fine but generates those extra pages.

Is there a way to suppress the backmatter in the Latex output when running with `COMPACT_LATEX=NO` ?

Perhaps this is a bug in Doxygen?

Thanks
 --Louis

Comment: I think this problem is described in Bug 742427 - latex compilation: \backmatter incompatible with COMPACT_LATEX=YES (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742427).

Comment: Hi Albert, yes that seems to describe the problem. Hopefully next release. Meanwhile, you can hand edit refman.tex (but it's a bit messy). Thanks.